# Could I provide the Free Subscription IAP to normal application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, xcode7

I have created an application which allows user to promote their event in their region.

And for promote their event the user need to buy the `IAP` based on their requirement.

**For promotion purpose :** I need to provide the Free `IAP` which act as user can promote their event to certain km or miles.

So my question is could I able to integrate the `Free Subscription` option which provided by Apple.

**Note :** As per the guideline of IAP for `Free Subscription`, the application should be type of magazine or newsstand, but my application is not fulfil this clause.

So is there any chance that Apple can reject my application.

Sorry for the long question but I did not get any valuable information from Google that's why I have to explain my requirement so other colleague can have a better idea for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to ask this question on [Apple Developer Forum](https://developer.apple.com/devforums/) where their developer can review their question and accordingly respond it.

Comment: As it partially answer the question but at least I have got the hint where to post on it.